# How to shift sum of cosines and constants by 90 degrees

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Suppose that $f(t) = a+ cos(\omega_1 t) + cos(\omega_2 t) +...$, where every $\omega_i$ is multiples of $\omega_1$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$. We want to shift this sum by 90 degrees to right.

Without first subtracting $a$, is there a simple equation for handling this?

Comment: What is right shifting?Should $f(t) $ increase by $\pi/2$?

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $$f(t) = f_0(t)+f_1(t)+f_2(t)+\dots$$
Where
$$f_0(t)=a,f_k(t)=\cos(\omega_kt),k\gt0$$
$f_0$ is a constant function (so it is already shifted to the right). How can you shift $f_k$ to the right?